# symlink() creating .system file instead of .symlink file in windows

Tags: c, windows, symlink

This case is used for the mix of windows and UNIX based os's. When used symlink() its works fine for UNIX/Linux but when same applied on windows instead of a symbolic link file .system file gets created.

Is there any C API I can use for which supports both OS's.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: In short: No there isn't. For starters, in Windows you have to decide if you want to create a *shortcut* or a file-system link or a file-system fork. I think that NTFS support a few different kinds of "links" (shortcuts not included).

Comment: yes understood, In other terms any C API for only windows, which does "mklink <linkname> <filepath>" (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/mklink)

Comment: NTFS has reparse points. This is an extension of NT object-namespace reparsing into the filesystem namespace. A reparse point buffer that's set on a file or directory might target a full reparse to another absolute path or relative path in the system, or it might be handled inline by a filter driver (e.g. swap in a file from hierarchical storage). Each type is identified by a registered tag, so system and third-party reparse points don't interfere. Common system types are `IO_REPARSE_TAG_MOUNT_POINT` and `IO_REPARSE_TAG_SYMLINK`, which emulate Unix mount points and symlinks.

Comment: At a high level, the Windows API supports creating symlinks via [`CreateSymbolicLinkW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-createsymboliclinkw). The caller needs to have the privilege "SeCreateSymbolicLinkPrivilege", which is granted to elevated administrators -- or can be granted to specific users or groups, in which case elevation is not required. Another difference with Windows symlinks is that a link that targets a directory must be set as a reparse point on a directory, so there's a flag `SYMBOLIC_LINK_FLAG_DIRECTORY` to specify this.